# Separator between ListView and TextView on Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, textview

As you can see in image below, under the ListView appear a black line before the TextView (footer).

[image]

I'm not able to understand if it's due a bottom padding of the listview or a top padding of the textview, so I've tried manipulating the xml layout adding android:layout_marginBottom="0px" and android:paddingBottom="0px" into the listview and android:paddingTop="0px" and android:layout_marginTop="0px" into the textview but nothing works!

Please help me because I've no idea how to solve the problem!!!

Here the xmls of the layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/header"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:background="#777777"
/>
<ListView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/items_list"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0px"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
    android:paddingBottom="0px"
/>      
<TextView 
    android:paddingTop="0px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/footer" 
    android:gravity="center" android:textSize="22sp"
    android:background="#777777/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here the layout of the item into the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingBottom="0px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
    android:background="#777777">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="Item List"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:textSize="22sp" 
    />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="List Item bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:layout_below="@id/item"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="List Item right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why that black line is there either, but maybe you should try to use [ListView.addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)) instead

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug. There is a hackaround. In your `ListView` write this:

```
<ListView ... android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp" />
```

This will fix this particular issue.

Having said that, I want to mention one more time that you should use [`ListView.addFooterView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) or you can use `layout_weight`:

```
<ListView       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"         
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#888888"
    ...
/>
```

[image]

Select the approach that fits you needs best. But note that "-3dp" is a hack, and should not be used (unless you are desperate :).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the android:footerDividersEnabled attribute to false and see if that helps.